# calling asmx web service from jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asmx

I am not able to call web service(asmx) from jQuery function.

It is saying "access denied" error while calling web service. It is working in the dev and local machine but I am getting the same error.

Here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://server.com/calculator.asmx/calculus",
            data: "{ 'userID': '" + $("#usrid").val() + "','password': '" + $("#password").val() + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: Success,
            error: Error
        });
```

My web service is

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.company.com/webservices/calculus")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class calculator : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=false, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
   public bool calculus(string userName, string password)
    {// my code}
```

The error is in  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js  function and
the "Access denied" error at e.username?x.open(n,e.url,e.async,e.username,e.password):x.open(n,e.url,e.async);

I have included  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)] with the class as shown in http://forums.asp.net/p/1570168/3935094.aspx  and not able to fix the prob. Can any one please help me regarding this.

Thank you

Comment: Is the web service on another domain?

Comment: Agree with @Nick, sounds (and looks) like a cross domain issue

Comment: I'm not sure, but with dataType 'json' shouldn't your data be an object rather than a string?

Comment: Yeah. the web service in another domain. It actually working in the local server though but not from any client web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is a possible way to workaround the "same origin policy" (aka cross-site-scripting or XSS) limitations.  It comes with its own set of challenges (for example, it works only with GET-mode requests), so it's certainly not a panacea.  But it's probably worth your time to give it a look.  There's a decent number of stackoverflow postings about it, which should help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX calls are bound to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) meaning that you cannot invoke a web service which is situated on a different domain. The browser will simply drop the request. One possible solution would be to write a server side script on the same domain which will serve as bridge to the actual web service and then call this script.

Comment: Thanks Darin. i figured out the prob. This is cross domain issue. But now the problem is calling web service working fine from IE but neither from mozilla or chrome.. I can see web methods and all when I give the direct url but it is not calling from jQuery again